# Implementation of SDUI using Flutter

Tags: node.js, json, flutter, sdui

I am building a Flutter application and am making the UI server driven. I have used `mirai: ^0.5.1` for converting JSON to widgets, but this library has missing implementation for widgets like PageView and no implementation for the functions like `onPageChanged(int index)` or `onPressed()` in BottomNavigationBar

Currently I have used Firebase Cloud Functions as server to listen to the HTTPS requests and returns the respective JSON. I have implemented only the UIs available in the Mirai's example app, but using them in my production apps is not feasible as `onClick`, `onChange` events are not handled.

Could someone please guide me how can we implement widgets like `ListViews`, `PageViews`, `BottomNavigationBars` using JSON or some sample project which I can refer to? Any suggestions regarding implementing SDUI are welcome.